# Comando select para excluir duplicados, somando os resultados

Tags: mysql, select

Como fazer para alterar uma tabela que está assim:

`produto | quant
    a    |   10
    a    |    5
    b    |    8
    b    |    3`

E deixá-la assim:

`produto | quant
    a    |   15
    b    |   11`

Existe algum comando `select` que eu possa usar para fazer essa modificação?

Comment: No título você diz excluir, mas no corpo da pergunta você mostra a junção dos registros. Ficou confuso.

Comment: Seria bem interessante ter sua query, porém nesse caso voê deveria utilizar o group_by coluna

Comment: acredito que é duplicata também, o link que Sorack postou deve resolver seu problema

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss foi erro de explicação mesmo. A ideia é excluir os nomes dos produtos repetidos, mas mantendo o valor da soma de todos eles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser deletar a de menor quantidade:

```
DELETE p1
  FROM produto p1
       INNER JOIN produto p2 ON p1.produto = p2.produto
 WHERE p1.quant < p2.quant;
```

Se quiser deletar a de maior quantidade:

```
DELETE p1
  FROM produto p1
       INNER JOIN produto p2 ON p1.produto = p2.produto
 WHERE p1.quant > p2.quant;
```

Caso queira agrupar os registros ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
 SELECT p.produto,
        SUM(p.quant) AS quant
   FROM produto p
  GROUP BY p.produto;
```

Caso queira agrupar e depois excluir, faça uma solução após a outra:

```
 SELECT p.produto,
        SUM(p.quant) AS quant
   FROM produto p
  GROUP BY p.produto;

DELETE p1
  FROM produto p1
       INNER JOIN produto p2 ON p1.produto = p2.produto
 WHERE p1.quant < p2.quant;
```